# Django: Creating form to add related data

Tags: python, django, orm, relationship

I have problem to undestand ORM in Django.
I have 3 models and 2 of them use first as FK.
I want to create buttons/forms which allow me to add related data.

My **models.py**

```
*imports*
class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self,name,surname):
        return self.get(name=name,surname=surname)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(attributes)
    surname = models.CharField(attributes)
    objects = PersonManager()

class Phone(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person.editable=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = model.CharField(attributes)

class Email(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,editable=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email - models.EmailField()
```

I have form which I use to add persons to database and now I want to add buttons near to each object person which will allow me to fill phone and email, but to be honest I have no idea in which way I can connect them together

**EDIT:**

To be more specyfic:

my **views.py**

```
*imports*
class PersonListView(ListView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'app/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'users' //(in my home method it returns person from db)
```

Now, near to each object I want to add button which will allow me to fill email

My **home.html**:

```
{% extends "app/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for user in users %}
id {{ user.id }} name: {{ user.name}} surname: {{ user.surname}}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You connect them together when you save them. You should show the form and view and explain where you are having trouble.

Comment: @DanielRoseman edited, I hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use related name for get relational field like this :

```
class Email(models.Model):
person= models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="E_person")
email - models.EmailField()
```

when you want to save this field in view first you create object from person class like this:

```
obj = person.objects.create(name="mrX",surname="mrXIII")
```

and for save email use :

```
obj.E_person.email = "mrX@gmail.com"
obj.save()
```

I this could help you.